# Unable to inherit in OpenAPI 3 using allOf in java

Tags: java, inheritance, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Please find the schemas in my contract yaml file :

```
Foo:
  allOf:
    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Bar"
  properties:
    ancestors:
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Bar"
      type: array
    description:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
    id:
      description: id
      type: string
  type: object
Bar:
  properties:
    accessAllowed:
      items:
        type: string
      type: array
    catalog:
      type: boolean
    children:
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Bar"
      type: array
```

While using swagger 2, the generated class Foo extends Bar. But after using openAPI 3 Foo isn't extending Bar when using `allOf`. All it is doing is copying all the properties of Bar to Foo class.

Although now that Foo class will contain all the properties of Bar, Foo isn't actually inheriting when we look at the java code side. Is there any way to generate the class Foo extending Bar when using OpenAPI 3 as there are many cases where one need to generate classes that inherit a parent class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add:

```
...
Bar:
  ...
  discriminator:
    propertyName: barType
    mapping:
      foo: "#/components/schemas/Foo"
  ...
...
```

Complete example:

```
Foo:
  allOf:
    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Bar"
  properties:
    ancestors:
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Bar"
      type: array
    description:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
    id:
      description: id
      type: string
  type: object
Bar:
  discriminator:
    propertyName: barType
    mapping:
      foo: "#/components/schemas/Foo"
  properties:
    accessAllowed:
      items:
        type: string
      type: array
    catalog:
      type: boolean
    children:
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Bar"
      type: array
```

Comment: It took so much time to find someone with an answer. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thank you ! This is so badly documented by openapi.

Comment: I still don't get Foo as a class.
How do you use Bar, is there a need to mention Foo somewhere outside of this file?

Answer (score 0):

with maven plugin, you need add config

```
<openapiNormalizer>REF_AS_PARENT_IN_ALLOF=true</openapiNormalizer>
```

it will inherit the first alloff object without discriminator

Comment: You forgot that it also needs the "x-parent: true" property inside the Parent schema.
Source: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/14172